# How can i use this "created at" field in firebase to use toDate() to get date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is a space that prevents the program to execute:

```
console.log(recipe.created at.toDate());
```

How can I use this "created at" field?

Answer (score 1):

If your field name contains a space you can't use `.` notation to access it, as an identifier can't contain spaces. Luckily you can use `[]` to access the properties too:

```
console.log(recipe["created at"].toDate());
```